# Deleting table entries based on criteria in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, subquery, sql-delete

We want to be able to delete entries from a MySQL table, based on deletion criteria set in another table.  Let me explain with an example.
I have two tables defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE base_tbl
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  f1 VARCHAR(8),
  f2 VARCHAR(8),
  
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE del_criteria_tbl
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  f3 VARCHAR(8),
  f4 VARCHAR(8),
  
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

`base_tbl` has the data and `del_criteria_tbl` has the criteria for deleting entries from `base_tbl`.

I populate the tables as follows:

```
INSERT INTO base_tbl(f1, f2) VALUES ('ABC', '123C57'),
('ABC', '532B49'), ('DEF', '397F45'),
('DEF', '684G65'), ('GHI', '793A86'),
('GHI', '541H32');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO del_criteria_tbl(f3, f4) VALUES ('ABC', '532B49'),
('ABC', '813E89'), ('DEF', '397F45'),
('GHI', '541H32');
```

Obviously:

```
mysql>SELECT * FROM base_tbl;
+----+------+--------+
| id | f1   | f2     |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | ABC  | 123C57 |
|  2 | ABC  | 532B49 |
|  3 | DEF  | 397F45 |
|  4 | DEF  | 684G65 |
|  5 | GHI  | 793A86 |
|  6 | GHI  | 541H32 |
+----+------+--------+


mysql>SELECT * FROM del_criteria_tbl;
+----+------+--------+
| id | f3   | f4     |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | ABC  | 532B49 |
|  2 | ABC  | 813E89 |
|  3 | DEF  | 397F45 |
|  4 | GHI  | 541H32 |
+----+------+--------+
```

---

I would like to define a succinct and efficient SQL operation that executes the following pseudo-SQL logic:

```
DELETE FROM base_tbl WHERE base_tbl.f1 = del_criteria_tbl.f3 AND base_tbl.f2 = del_criteria_tbl.f4
```

After the operation is executed, `SELECT * FROM base_tbl` should yield:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | f1   | f2     |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | ABC  | 123C57 |
|  4 | DEF  | 684G65 |
|  5 | GHI  | 793A86 |
+----+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is `IN`:

```
DELETE b FROM base_tbl b
    WHERE (b.f1, b.f2) IN (SELECT dc.f3, dc.f4
                           FROM del_criteria_tbl dc
                          );
```

With indexes on `(f1, f2)`, you might find a `JOIN` has better performance:

```
DELETE b
    FROM base_tbl b JOIN
         del_criteria_tbl dc
         ON b.f1 = dc.f3 AND b.f2 = c.f4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `exists`:

```
delete b
from base_tbl b
where exists (
    select 1
    from del_criteria_tbl dc
    where dc.f1 = b.f1 and dc.f2 = b.f2
)
```

This seems like the most natural way to phrase what you ask for. `exists` usually scales better than `in` over large datasets. For performance, you want an index on `del_criteria_tbl(f1, f2)`.